# Web table scraping: can't get result from a unicode list

Tags: python, unicode, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a web table scraping using python and beautiful soup. The web page is in Chinese. in the table, each row has four elements (all in Chinese) When I do this, it prints correct Chinese characters - all four elements for all rows.

```
            table = soup.find('table', {'class': "tc_table"})               
            trs = table.find_all('tr')
            for tr in trs:
                    ls = []
                    for td in tr.find_all('td'):
                            ls.append(td.text)   

                    ls = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in ls]
                    for i in ls:
                            print(i)
```

However, what I need is only third and fourth element from each row. Hence, I modified my code into the following, but it seems that there is IndexError:

File "taocan.py", line 83, in get_data_from_link

print(ls[2])

IndexError: list index out of range

```
      table = soup.find('table', {'class': "tc_table"})               
      trs = table.find_all('tr')
      for tr in trs:
              ls = []
              for td in tr.find_all('td'):
                      ls.append(td.text)   

              ls = [x.encode('utf-8') for x in ls]
              print(ls[2])
              print(ls[3])
```

Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: You make the assumption that all `tr` elements contains at least 4 `td` children. However, it's common for the first row to use `th` instead of `td`.  There could also be other reasons why a html table have fever cells in some rows.  You should try-except when accessing indexed items that might not exists.

Comment: wow it seems it works now. Thank you for the suggestion!;D